# How to add Firebase Image URL to input and submit to Database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm building an Angular form where I can add project Name, Description, Image, and link and submit to save information in Firebase. Then in another component pull that information and display on page.

**What i'm able to do:**
I'm able to upload the image to Firebase storage and submit ProjectName, Description and link to database but I'm having issue with saving image URL in database.

[angular form to add project img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dBFG.png)

**What I'm having issue with:**
After I upload the image I want to get it's url and add it to Project Link input field and submit to database to save it along with other fields. That's the part I'm having issue with, after I upload the image I'm not able to add it's value to input. I tried binding it with [value]="url" but that doesn't work unless I remove name="image". in that case I get the image url value in field but get error.

[Form Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DIGZ.png)

Here is my component.html file

```
 <div class="card-body">
 <form #projectForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(projectForm)">  



   //UPLOAD IMAGE AND ADD THE URL TO INPUT

    <div *ngIf="(snapshot | async) as snap">
    {{ snap.bytesTransferred | fileSize }} of {{ snap.totalBytes | fileSize }} 


    <div *ngIf="downloadURL | async as url">
    <h3>Results!</h3>
    <img width="150px" #var height="auto" [src]="url"><br>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Project Link</label><br>
        <input 
          [value]="url"
          name="image"
          #projectImage="ngModel"
          class="form-control"
          [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':projectImage.errors && projectImage.touched}"
          [(ngModel)]="project.image"
          minlength="2"
          required
          readonly
        >
      </div>
    </div> 
    <hr>

    </div>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my component.ts file

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from 
 '@angular/core';
import { Project } from '../../models/Project';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-project',
  templateUrl: './add-project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-project.component.scss']
})
export class AddProjectComponent implements OnInit { 
  project: Project = {
    projName: '',
    description: '',
    image: '',
    link: ''
    }
  @ViewChild('projectForm') form: any;  
  constructor(
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage, 
    private db: AngularFirestore
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }



 // Download URL
 downloadURL: Observable<string>;




// The file's download URL
this.snapshot.pipe(finalize(() => this.downloadURL = this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL())).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code to go through in your example, can you remove the code thats irrelevant to the question?

Comment: @sketchthat I have removed the unnecessary code. In TS file with downloadUrl I'm able to get the image URL and in HTML file I'm able to add it to image '[src]="url"' which works fine but it's the input that I'm having an issue with. Under input '[value]="url" name="image"' doesn't work together.

Comment: You should need to use both `[value]` and `ngModel`. If you set `project.image = url` it and remove the `[value]` property does it work as expected. Also the error message has some solutions for you to try.